The Photos app on the iOS 18 simulator does not support the JPEG-XL format, unlike the real device running iOS 18
On Xcode 16 simulator running iOS 18, when dragging and dropping an image with a .jxl extension (JPEG-XL format) into the Photos app, the Messages app opens!
Another way to do this using the terminal is:
xcrun simctl addmedia booted <imagePath.jxl>
This command failed with the following error:
Failed to import <imagePath.jxl>, error [NSPOSIXErrorDomain] 22: The operation couldn’t be completed. File type unsupported.
Is there something I missed to enable JPEG-XL support in the simulator, or is this a bug?

That sounds like a question for Apple, not for us.
